# How can you use a font file in GTK

Tags: python, linux, fonts, gtk

I'm writing an open source program (key-train) in Python and GTK (with Cairo) and I would like to use some more attractive fonts.  I was hoping that it would be possible to load a ttf font from within the program and just use it (instead of installing it), but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this feature request](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347237) It shows a work-a-round if using cairo and freetype for the backend.

Comment: So I'll take this to mean that there's no proper way to do this yet, but there might be in the future.
There are hacks that may work.

For my program I've decided to go another way:

  - For the seven segment font I wanted to use, I'll just use 10 svg images which I've created myself (see http://scottkirkwood.blogspot.com/2009/12/seven-segment-display-in-inkscape.html).

  - For any additional fonts I'll install them as part of the the install.

Comment: I think that's a good decision. Nice looking program, btw. I'm going to have to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pango to set the ttf font:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pango
import gtk

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
main_vbox = gtk.VBox(homogeneous=False,spacing=0)
window.add(main_vbox)
textview = gtk.TextView()
main_vbox.pack_start(textview,expand=False,fill=True,padding=0)
textbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
font_desc=pango.FontDescription('FreeSans Bold 64')
textview.modify_font(font_desc)
textbuffer.set_text('Hi Scott Kirkwood')
textview.show()
main_vbox.show()
window.show()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: This I know how to do, I'm more interested in loading a ttf file.